# Problem with "Sign in with Google temporarily disabled for this app"

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

My app has been OAuth verified for youtube and youtube.upload.

When I OAuth with these scopes, it's still not working.

I get the following in the web browser as before verification. They closed out my ticket, so I have no means to contact them.

Sign in with Google temporarily disabled for this app
This app has not been verified yet by Google in order to use Google Sign In.

If you are a developer for this application, please submit a verification request to re-enable Sign in with Google. Learn more

Please advise

Answer (score 1):

> Sign in with Google temporarily disabled for this app This app has not been verified yet by Google in order to use Google Sign In.
>
> If you are a developer for this application, please submit a verification request to re-enable Sign in with Google. Learn more

The message you are getting clearly states the issue.  Your application is not verified or its verification has bee removed.  In order to fix this you must go thought he verification process.   You might want to check your email and see if there is any messages from google as to why your verification was removed.  I have seen several posts like this over the last week it seams Google may be going though projects.

Comment: My OP clearly stated that "My app has been OAuth verified for youtube and youtube.upload.". I.e. It's already verified. That is why I opened my post with that statement to avoid these comments, but it didnt work.